# What is the origin of an image added to a canvas in FabricJS?

Tags: fabricjs

Why when you add an image to the canvas, it does not begin with the 0x0, and from -this.width / 2,-this.height / 2 ?

Comment: If you want to save yourself, edit the Title to be a question.

Answer (score 3):

The default origin point is the center. You can change this behavior setting [`object.originX`](http://fabricjs.com/docs/symbols/fabric.Object.html#originX) and [`object.originY`](http://fabricjs.com/docs/symbols/fabric.Object.html#originY).